# What is the possible tree diagram for O(n²) time complexity?

Tags: tree, big-o

This is my code for calculating the height in a tree data structure which is the worst case with `O(n²)` run time complexity:

```
public int heightBad(){

int h = 0
for (Position<E> p: positions())
  if (isExternal(p))
    h = Math.max(h, depth(p));
  return h;
}

public int depth(Position<E> p){

  if (isRoot(p))
    return 0;
  else
    return 1 + depth(parent(p));
 }
```

I know the time complexity is `O(n²)` but i wanted some help in representing this as a tree diagram.
I am assuming the root `T` have 2 children, say `x`, `y`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it has O(n^2) because for each element examined, all the other elements (or most part of them) are re-examined.(or re-traversed)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a graph, that forces the worst possible running time of your algorithm. This would be a tree with only one child node for each node.

[image: input-graph]

If you are looking for a call tree, that shows the `O(n²)` complexity, you can simply write down the call graph of your algorithm for the input graph I showed.

[image: call-graph]

I hope this is what you are looking for.